# In angularjs/ionic app, select and input values are remaining the same after loading new data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a small web app that allows users to search for new items or select items that they have previously searched for saved to a menu. The issue I am having is that after a user uses the master search and then searches from their saved search, the input field is not being updated to new search text.

Also, the select values for each of the searches remain the same after the data is loaded. The correct values are being passed through the API, but the actual select is not changing.

You can see the web app here: http://dev.sortsof.com.

Try searching for an item. Then search for another.

Use the left hand menu to load your original item, you will see that the search field does not update to the correct search terms.

Also, the select will not reset back to the first select after each new set of items is loaded.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You are using a form right? you can use just an input with `[(ngModel)]="searchInput"` that will do the two-ways binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $scope.search = searchterm ; 
    $scope.$apply() ;
```